# interpolate NA only for the last value

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation, na

In R, in a data frame, I know that I can fill all of the NA values with the last available value using `na.approx()`.

However, how can I do if I only want to do it for the last available value, not for all of the NAs, as in this example:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA)
```

Becoming:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10)
```

My first intuition was to first test if the last value is a NA, and then test the last non-NA value. Is there any faster method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find the index of the last non-NA, then get the sequence from that point to `length` of 'a' and assign those with the last non-NA

```
i1 <- tail(which(!is.na(a)), 1)
a[i1:length(a)] <- a[i1]
a
#[1]  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA  8  9 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following code

```
a[-(1:tail(which(!is.na(a)),1))] <- tail(a[!is.na(a)],1)
```

such that

```
> a
 [1]  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA  8  9 10 10 10
```